# error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I am trying to do something along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135457/how-to-write-a-wrapper-over-functions-and-member-functions-that-executes-some-cod/2140112#2140112), and struggling:

`$ gcc --version

gcc (GCC) 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)`

```
file.cpp:7: error: template argument 1 is invalid  
file.cpp:7: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
```

And the offending part of the file:

```
template <class R, class C, class T0=void, class T1=void, class T2=void>
struct MemberWrap;

template <class R, class C, class T0>
struct MemberWrap<R, C, T0>{
    typedef R (C::*member_t)(T0);
    typedef typename boost::add_reference<typename T0>::type> TC0; // <---- offending line

    MemberWrap(member_t f)
        : m_wrapped(f){
    }

    R operator()(C* p, TC0 p0){
        GILRelease guard;
        return (p->*(this->m_wrapped))(p0);
    }

    member_t m_wrapped;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop `typename` from `typename T0` in

```
typedef typename boost::add_reference<typename T0>::type> TC0;
```

and probably drop the second angle bracket as well. I.e.

```
typedef typename boost::add_reference<T0>::type TC0;
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that!